# How to access block device inside a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, containers, block, device

I have been trying to access block storage device of host system from a docker container though binding mount. Getting 'Operation not permitted' error.

Is there anything that I'm missing here:

```
# ls -l /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Sep  3 00:52 /dev/sdb
# 
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
16005+0 records in
16005+0 records out
16782458880 bytes (17 GB) copied, 12.4396 s, 1.3 GB/s

# 
# 
# docker container run --name c1 -it --mount type=bind,source=/dev/sdb,target=/data centos
/# ls -l /data
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Sep  3 06:52 /data
/# 
/#
/# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data bs=1M
dd: failed to open '/data': Operation not permitted
/#
```

Comment: I don't think you can bindmount a device. You need to mount it on your host system, then bindmount the folder where you mounted it into the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For hardware device, you will need to give capabilities to container to operation the device, there are 2 options here:

**Option 1: Use privileged**

See [Full container capabilities (--privileged)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#full-container-capabilities---privileged):

```
# docker container run --rm --privileged --name c1 -it --mount type=bind,source=/dev/sdb,target=/data centos
[root@7ab2eaef67cd /]# ls -al /data
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Sep  3 08:13 /data
[root@7ab2eaef67cd /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data bs=1 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0.00710505 s, 0.1 kB/s
[root@7ab2eaef67cd /]# exit
exit
```

**Option 2: Use --device**

See [Add host device to container (--device)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container---device):

```
# docker container run --rm --name c1 -it --device=/dev/sdb:/data centos
[root@3a05b15b3b96 /]# ls -al /data
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Sep  3 08:15 /data
[root@3a05b15b3b96 /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data bs=1 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0.00326708 s, 0.3 kB/s
[root@3a05b15b3b96 /]# exit
exit
```

Comment: Thank atline, for great help. It worked perfectly fine

Comment: Adding `--device=/dev/sdb` or a `devices: /dev/sdb:/dev/sdb` in docker-composer works. But after this, how can I automatically mount the block device to a specific position at `/data` when I do `docker run` or `docker-compose up`

Comment: If you could manually mount that & just search for a automatically solution, then write your own dockerfile with `FROM centos`, and define the auto mount in `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `--device` flag to pass any kind of device to a container, the doc isn't the most complete on this feature but it's simple enough, something like `docker container run --name c1 -it --device=/dev/sdb centos` should work fine.

Of course you'll then have to mount it inside your container unto `/data`.

Comment: Thank Tzig, for the response. --device option also worked